# How to model two sided objects like handkerchief or piece of paper?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, faces

I'm trying to model a handkerchief to use in another program and I've seen few approaches to modeling flat objects with two sides, the problem is I can't decide which one is more efficient. (less vertices and problems when I add Subsurf and Cloth modifiers).

1. create a plane and extrude a little bit.
2. create a plane and duplicate it in edit mode the flip the normal.
3. I've tried the cycle texturing trick with a single plane but it didn't export the textures with it.

Is there any other way I can try? Which one do you suggest? What about a piece of pepper?
Keep in mind that I'm trying to texture both sides.

Comment: Where do you want to export it? Blender has double-sided option but I don't know if software you are aiming accept it.

Comment: mainly daz3D and it's iray rendering

Comment: Have you tried the solidify modifier?

Comment: does solidify give me two surfaces to texture before applying? is it more efficient than extruding? specially while simulating the cloth